# how to integrate payment gateway in Node,js web app

Tags: html, node.js, payment-gateway, payment

I am relatively new to Node.js can someone please link a documentation/or explain the process of integrating the Node.js app with a payment getaway ??

Comment: [Google.com](https://google.com)

Comment: go to the website of such providers. like paytm or so. you can see the documentation for integrating it. you can see the nodejs code snippets too there